# How to book ride i uber using Uber API

Tags: uber-api

I am using sandbox for testing purpose and whenever I am trying to book a ride using "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests" with all the needed params,headers and method it always returning that "status" is "processing".
I dont know how to move forward and for how long the status will be hold.

Can you give any suggestion so that I can move forward.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox does not automatically move through a ride but must manually be put through each state:

"Currently, the sandbox does not change states automatically the way a real request in production would. This endpoint gives the ability to walk an application through the different states of a ride request."

Please see the sandbox guide for more details: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/sandbox